# Unexpected token when saving PHP variable in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I have the following function on my Wordpress site to put a class on a ID when the date is correct. The problem is that a line break is created within the Javascript variable when it reads the file that you have previously created with the IDs.

```
function ProgramarBorrado(){

    //Get day, month and year
    $date = getdate();
    $day = $date['mday'];
    $month = $date['mon'];
    $year = $date['year'];

    //Create a list
    $list = array();

    //Open/create a file
    $myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "w+");

    //If true push an ID on a list
    if(($day==5)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
        array_push($list,"#borrar22marc");
    }

    if(($day==5)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
        array_push($list,"#prova");
    }

    //For each value of the list, write in the file lista.txt
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        fwrite($myfile, $value."\n");
    }

    //Close write mode
    fclose($myfile);

    //Open read mode
    $myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "r");

    //Get the value of each line of the file
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
      ?>
            <script>
                //Save the PHP variable on a JS variable
                var simple = '<?php echo fgetss($myfile) ;?>';
                console.log(simple);
                //Add class with jQuery
                jQuery(simple).addClass('borrar-programado');
            </script>
        <?php
        }

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ProgramarBorrado');
```

This is the error:

```
                //Save the PHP variable on a JS variable
                var simple = '#borrar22marc
';
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetss.php: _“This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.3.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.”_

Comment: `trim` the value before you output it, or make your life a little easier by reading the file content into an array using just `file`.

Comment: I tried with fgets() too and the problem persists

Comment: Yes! I try the trim function and has been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! trim function is the solution, thanks to 04FS for the solution, this is how the code is after the solution:

```
function ProgramarBorrado(){

    //Get day, month and year
    $date = getdate();
    $day = $date['mday'];
    $month = $date['mon'];
    $year = $date['year'];

    //Create a list
    $list = array();

    //Open/create a file
    $myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "w+");

    //If true push an ID on a list
    if(($day==5)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
        array_push($list,"#borrar22marc");
    }

    if(($day==5)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
        array_push($list,"#prova");
    }

    //For each value of the list, write in the file lista.txt
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        fwrite($myfile, $value."\n");
    }

    //Close write mode
    fclose($myfile);

    //Open read mode
    $myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "r");

    //Get the value of each line of the file
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
      ?>
            <script>
                //Save the PHP variable on a JS variable
                var simple = '<?php echo trim(fgets($myfile)) ;?>';
                console.log(simple);
                //Add class with jQuery
                jQuery(simple).addClass('borrar-programado');
            </script>
        <?php
        }

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ProgramarBorrado');
```